# Unable to conform activation

Tags: apple-configurator, mobile-device-management

I am trying to get our home devices supervised, starting with an iPhone 3GS running 6.1.3.

I'm using a Mac OS X Server (iMac - OS X 10.9 and Server v3) and Apple Configurator 1.4.2.

First step, Prepare. I turn on the supervision flag, accept the rest of the defaults and click go.

6.1.3 is reinstalled on the iPhone fine, then AC errors out with, 'Cannot Conform Activation'.

I tried multiple times, all with the same result. I do see a dialog on the iTunes-like window that appears about a Carrier upgrade, but AC has failed before I see that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was just something on Apple's side and the activation went through today!